# Script will be halted because of file.read()

Tags: python, file

I want to read the input from an USB mouse (directly, without an GUI).
This already does qork quite well.
Unfortunately, it seems like the code within the while-block will only be executed when there are values in the buffer.
As a result, the heartbeat will not be executed regularly.
How should I re-write the script so I can continuosly execute code within the while-loop?

Thank you very much for you help in advance!
Sebastian

```
### ORIGINAL VERSION ###
import struct
import time

path = "/dev/input/by-id/usb-_mini_keyboard-if01-event-mouse"

file = open(path, "rb")

while True:

# Read the data from the USB interface:
byte = file.read(16)
(type, code, value) = struct.unpack_from('hhi', byte, offset=8)

print("Type: " + str(type) + " Code: " + str(code) + " Value: " + str(value))

# Detect mouse presses:
if type == 1 and value == 1:
    if code == 272:
        print("LEFT PRESS")
    if code == 273:
        print("RIGHT PRESS")

time.sleep(1)
print("++++ HEARTBEAT ++++")

### THREADING VERSION ###
import struct
import time
from threading import Thread

path = "/dev/input/by-id/usb-_mini_keyboard-if01-event-mouse"

file = open(path, "rb")

def readUSB():

# Read the data from the USB interface:
byte = file.read(16)
(type, code, value) = struct.unpack_from('hhi', byte, offset=8)

# Detect mouse presses:
if type == 1 and value == 1:
    if code == 272:
        print("LEFT PRESS")
    if code == 273:
        print("RIGHT PRESS")

while True:
    t = Thread(target=readUSB())
    t.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    print("**** HEARTBEAT ****")
```

Comment: See the `select` syscall (which can be told to wake your program up when something is ready to be read it written, or when a timer has passed). I don't remember where Python keeps its wrapper for it, but that's the underlying OS interface you want (in conjunction with setting your file handle non-blocking)

Comment: One easy method would be to move this loop into its own thread.  Since you'll spend most of your time blocked in the `read` call, the GIL won't hurt you.  The other method is to use `select`, but that's more difficult.

Comment: Would `fcntl.fcntl(file, fcntl.F_SETFL, flag | os.O_NONBLOCK)` help? Then you wouldn't need `select`...`read` should return instatntly with `None` if nothing is in the buffer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response!
I tried the threading, but it was the same behaviour.
I am attaching it to the original thread, did I make something wrong?

Comment: Yes, you did something wrong.  You need to create the thread once.  The `readUSB()` function will then have its own `while True` loop to run forever.

Comment: Even with its own while loop it didn´t work unfortunately.
But the os.nonblock did work!
I wrote it like this:
`os.set_blocking(file.fileno(), False)`
after the `file = open...` and
`if byte:...` after the `file.read...`
Thanks again everyone for the great help!